# mongodb: using lookup results as criteria for filtering not working for timestamps

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In the example below, I am trying to retrieve documents from the state collection that have a rule assignment where the current date is in the range of the current time.  If I comment out the bottom match condition, it works.  However, if I use the timestamp matching criteria it does not return any results.

How do I perform this query with mongodb?

```
state = { deferred: true, rule: ObjectId("5d83fd3a176edf9f4242622e") }
rules = { _id: ObjectId("5d83fd3a176edf9f4242622e"), start: 1568916000, end: 1568930400 }


db.state.aggregate([{
  $match: {
            { deferred: { $ne: null} }
        }
  },
  { 
    "$lookup": {
        from: "rules",
        localField: "rule",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "rules_current"
    }
  },
  {
     $unwind: "$rules_current"
  },
  {
     $match: {
         $and: [
             { "rules_current.start": { $lt: (new Date().getTime()) } },
             { "rules_current.end": { $gt: (new Date().getTime()) } }
        ]
     }
  }
])
```

Comment: *Query looks good*, state and end time in rules table is not falling under your *$and* condition.

Comment: Millis saved in db are since 1970 and will always be less than new Date().getTime(), please check same as 1568916000 millis is Mon Jan 19 1970 03:48:36 UTC

Comment: Then how should I do a between test?